# /bin/sh is a symbolic link that doesn't point to /bin/bash

Tags: bash, make, symbolic-link

I was installing the software environment of Armadeus experiment board APF27DEV, and when I tried the `make` command, it gave me the following error message:

```
On your system /bin/sh is a symbolic link that doesn't point to /bin/bash --> please correct that !
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 2013-08-03 20:57 /bin/sh -> dash
```

To resolve this error, I've tried to change all the shebangs from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`, and I've also tried the following command:

```
ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

But, all that I've done didn't resolve the problem. Could anyone please help me out with this problem?

Comment: This would be a bug in their software so you will need to take it up with them.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You were almost there with your `ln` command, except you probably needed to include the `-f` flag ('force') in order to overwrite the old link. Also it's preferable to use a relative path for the target:

```
sudo ln -sf bash /bin/sh
```

When you're done with the install, you can revert to the system default with:

```
sudo ln -sf dash /bin/sh
```

There should be no need to change the script file's [shebangs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Comment: It would be better to run `sudo dpkg-reconffigure dash` and choose the option to **not** use dash to provide `/bin/sh`. If you do it with dpkg, it will update other parts of your system (like the manpages) to match.

Comment: * `sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash`

Answer (score 2):

The problem must not be `/bin/sh` pointing at `dash` because that's default (I just checked on my end and it was the same). The problem must be elsewhere; the package doesn't seem to be compatible with Ubuntu out-of-the-box.

Perhaps in the Makefile you may find a line executing a script through `sh` explicitly, i.e. `sh path/to/script`. Replace all such occurrences of `sh` for `bash`, and report back your results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!! I've known a different way from what you've told me.